# Why Power remains same in a Transformer?

Tags: transformer

If we have a step up transformer then the voltage at the secondary side will be more than the voltage at the primary side. Since we all know that

POWER = VOLTAGE * CURRENT

and because voltage at the secondary side is now more than the voltage at the primary side.

So will it not make the power at the secondary side more that the power at the primary side according to the relation P=VI ?

Then why is it said that power will remain same at the both side of the transformer when voltage on both sides is not same ?

Comment: I think you're just missing the fact that current is greater on the input and less on the output.

Comment: Unfortunately law of conservation of energy exists in this universe ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$ P_{OUT} = P_{IN} - losses $$

Ignoring the losses:

$$ P_{OUT} = P_{IN}$$
$$ V_{OUT}I_{OUT} = V_{IN}I_{IN}$$

Rearranging:

$$ I_{OUT} = \frac {V_{IN}}{V_{OUT}}I_{IN}$$

So, for a step up transformer where V<sub>OUT</sub> > V<sub>IN</sub> the output current is less than the input current by the voltage step-up ratio.

---

From the comments:

> So if the voltage increases on secondary side then the current shouldnt increase also on secondary side ? doesnt the mathematical expression violates the ohm law in this case ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl2Pe0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two scenarios.*

- In (a) the current will be \$ \frac {V}{R} = \frac {120}{120} = 1 \ \text A \$.
- In (a) the power **in R1** will be \$ P = VI = 120 \times 1 = 120 \ \text W \$.
- In (a) the primary current will be 1 A.

If we use the same value resistor for R2 with double the voltage then we have situation (b).

- In (b) the current will be \$ \frac {V}{R} = \frac {240}{120} = 2 \ \text A \$.
- In (b) the power **in R2** will be \$ P = VI = 240 \times 2 = 480 \ \text W \$.
- In (b) the primary power will have to be at least 480 W.
- In (b) the primary current will have to be \$ I = \frac {P}{V} = \frac {480}{120} = 4 \ \text A \$.

The main thing you need to realise from the answers to your question is that **Ohm's law applies to the resistors R1 and R2, and not to the transformers!**

---

> In (b) the primary current will have to be 4 A ? How the primary side will manage to make the primary current high?

Transformers transform voltages and currents but this has the effect of transforming impedances too.

> **impedance**
>   /ɪmˈpiːd(ə)ns/
>   *noun*,
>   the effective resistance of an electric circuit or component to alternating current, arising from the combined effects of ohmic resistance and reactance.

So you can think of an impedance as resistance to AC.

The impedance seen looking into the primary in your step-up transformer will be \$ \frac {1}{n^2}Z_L \$, where *n* is the voltage step-up ratio. So with R2 = 120 Ω the mains supply will see a load of \$ \frac {1}{2^2}120 = 30 \ \Omega \$. Therefore the current will be 4 A.

Note that if R2 is removed and the transformer is open-circuit that no current will be drawn by the primary. (In real transformers there will be a little magnetizing current.)

Comment: Thats nice. Yes it make sense mathematically but ohm laws says that current is proportional to voltage . So if the voltage increases on secondary side then the current shouldnt increase also on secondary side ? doesnt the mathematical expression violates the ohm law in this case ?

Comment: @Alex well, that's exactly what happens: by the same factor you change the voltage, you inversely change the current. Nothing surprising here. A transformer is, quite obviously, not a resistor (to start with: it has four terminals and doesn't convert electrical energy to heat...)

Comment: @MarcusMüller current is directly proportional to current not inversely proportional . On secondary side we have higher voltage so secondary side is not supposed to supply the more current ?

Comment: @Alex no, again, this is not a resistor.

Comment: @Alex This seems to be a case of "all you know is a hammer so everything looks like a nail". For now, you might just have to be satisfied with the fact that you can only resistors follows Ohm's Law, and devices that are not resistors do not.

Comment: @Alex: See the update.

Comment: @Transistor really thanks alot. i have chosen your answer as best answer. just one more question. In (b) the primary current will have to be 4 A ? How the primary side will manage to make the primary current high ?

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 2):

If the voltage at the secondary is more than the voltage on the primary, then the current on the secondary will be LESS than current on the primary.

A transformer changes both voltage and current in such a way that the output power equals the input power (less a little for losses in the transformer).

Comment: Ohms law says that Voltage and current are directly proportional so if the voltage on the secondary is higher then it should supply more current on the secondary side than the current on the primary side.

Comment: Ohm's law applies to resistors and the like.

Comment: Your interpretation of Ohms law is wrong. Thats not the way you apply it in case of a transformer @Alex

Comment: then whats the right interpretation ?

Comment: @Alex that it got nothing to do with transformers.

Comment: "Voltage is directly proportional to current" - This is not even the Ohms law. There are contexts you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you **carefully** read through this transmogrification of your question it MAY help:

Note carefully that a transformer with more turns on the secondary than on the pimary is a current "step **down**" transformer. This is the main point that you have to appreciate in your "visualisation".

---

**Changing "voltage" to "current" and "up" to "down" in your original question":**

If we have a current step down transformer [secondary turns are more than primary turns] then the current at the secondary side will be less than the current at the primary side. Since we all know that

POWER = VOLTAGE * CURRENT

and because current at the secondary side is now less than the current at the primary side.

So will it not make the power at the secondary side more that the power at the primary side according to the relation P=VI ?

Then why is it said that power will remain same at the both side of the transformer when current on both sides is not same ?